# How is BBC changing colours based on temperature? CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How is BBC changing the background colour of the day time temperature in the link below?

http://news.bbc.co.uk/weather/forecast/4276?&search=gerrards%20cross&itemsPerPage=10&region=world&area=Gerrards%20Cross

Looks like the colour is based on the temperature.  I've tried looking at there css files, but can't see any colours associated to those class names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.core .temp-19-21, .extra-info .temp-19-21 {`

in `CSSMain.css`

Just use a DOM inspector like Chrome's Inspect Element or Firebug.